# Facebook like button for fan page is not working in android?

Tags: android, facebook

I implemented a Facebook like button from android application to like my facebook fan page.

**xml:**

```
 <com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView
    android:id="@+id/demoLike"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"></com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView>
```

**code snippet:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo_like);
    likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.demoLike);
    likeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.STANDARD);
    likeView.setAuxiliaryViewPosition(LikeView.AuxiliaryViewPosition.INLINE);
    likeView.setObjectIdAndType("http://www.facebook.com/MYPAGE", LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);}
```

But when i click the like button,it is not working.
I have used Facebook SDK 4.2,also used Facebook App ID in manifest file.

Comment: Are you getting some error? If so, post it.

Comment: When i clicked the like button,logcat shows "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://m.facebook.com/connect/dialog/proxy/graph. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://mobile.facebook.com' is therefore not allowed access."

Answer (score 0):

check your app project in developers.facebook.com. Make sure that your config is true.

Answer (score 0):

The Like Button worked very well after I tested on my friends smartphones.I do not know why it is not working on the emulator.But the "share" button really works fine on the emulator.Finally Facebook approved my application and its Facebook features.Feeling good:-)